# Sql Query for specific Date

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a SQL query as on my redshift cluster:-

```
select 
a.employee_id as "Employee ID",
a.transaction_id as "Transaction ID",
CONVERT_TIMEZONE('US/Pacific',a.created_datetime) as "Created Date Time",
a.status as Status,
a.pay_period_start as "Pay Period Start Date",
a.pay_period_end as "Pay Period End Date",
a.currency as "Payment Currency",
a.error_code as "Error Code",
CONVERT_TIMEZONE('US/Pacific',a.payment_datetime) as "Payment Date Time",
case when CONVERT_TIMEZONE('US/Pacific',a.payment_datetime) is null then null 
else datediff(minutes,CONVERT_TIMEZONE('US/Pacific',a.created_datetime),CONVERT_TIMEZONE('US/Pacific',a.payment_datetime)) end as Minus_To_Pay,
CONVERT_TIMEZONE('US/Pacific',a.update_datetime) as "Update Date Time",
a.amount as "Withdraws amount",
b.ngr
from (
select a.*
from transaction_service_internal.withdrawal_transaction a 
where a.update_time = (select max(update_time) from transaction_service_internal.withdrawal_transaction  b where b.transaction_id=a.transaction_id) 
) a
inner join
( 
select k.*
from transaction_service_internal.transaction_snapshot k 
where nvl(k.update_time, k.created_timestamp) = (select max(nvl(k1.update_time, k1.created_timestamp)) from transaction_service_internal.transaction_snapshot  k1 where k.transaction_id=k1.transaction_id) 
) b
on a.transaction_id=b.transaction_id
```

Here the entries returned have all the events with Payment Date Time uptil now (current time). I want all the entries of previous day (basis payment date time). For example if time right now is 2nd July in PST timezone then the query should return records with payment date time as 1st July only. Can someone pls help?

Comment: You know how to write a query like that, but not know how to put a WHERE clause on it?

Comment: Hey @CaiusJard , Actually I have not written this. It was present in one of our Quick sights report. Nevertheless, I know how to put a where clause but how do I manage to put it for current date - 1 sort of thing?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEADD_function.html)?

Comment: What database is it? MySQL <> PG

Comment: If you use Redshift, then why do you add postgres and MySQL tags?

Comment: @astentx RS is PG, no? Maybe we have to assume "best of 3" ;)

Comment: It's a Redshift cluster.

Comment: @astentx, I shouldnt have put tag of MySql here but queries over Redshift cluster follow the syntax of PostgreSQL, thats why I had put it.

Comment: @SakshamAgarwal you can remove the time from a date in a PG flavored db with DATE_TRUNC, and you can change the date with e.g. `- INTERVAL '1 DAY'` to go one date before it.. hence you can put a where clause that is `where tabledate >= midnight_yesterday and tabledate < midnight_just_passed`

Comment: Anyway, documentation page is a good starting point according to [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

> I want all the entries of previous day (basis payment date time). For example if time right now is 2nd July in PST timezone then the query should return records with payment date time as 1st July only.

You want a `WHERE` clause.  Based on your description, you want a filtering condition:

```
CONVERT_TIMEZONE('US/Pacific', a.payment_datetime)::date = CONVERT_TIMEZONE('US/Pacific', GETDATE())::date - INTERVAL '1 DAY'
```

That is, convert both the date/time value in the column and the current date/time to Pacific time and then extract the date.